# Function similar to x * Gaussian function, but with equal areas bounded by positive and negative sides

Tags: real-analysis, integration, curves, constraints

I would like to find a function which graphically resembles $xe^{-x^2}$, or similarly the $\psi_{1}$ eigenfunction of the Schrodinger equation, and has the following properties:

It is continuous and differentiable. Also, the value at which the function converges to near-$0$ with a near-$0$ slope on the left and the right are fixed (say, to $x = 0$ and $x = 1$), and within the domain $[0,1]$, the area enclosed by each hump separated by the point m at which the function crosses the x-axis is equal. Since the area outside of the bounds is negligible, the domain restriction for area is not important. I am hoping to easily toggle where the point m lies, and even when it is closer to the left or right bound, still maintain the property that their areas are equal. Attached is a demos sketch that has disproportionate humps (move s to change the crossing point): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0fnj3yxeru

and here is a partial solution, which is not differentiable at m: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ywxezwhpk6?fbclid=IwAR0iWXLgRXcbz3swvUGjR8jUk847o0IlVPFb1v_07ENgXTW7hfB8Hf_Zl0E

Comment: What is the context for which you need such a function?

Comment: I am trying to solve a collision avoidance problem that I asked about here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119926/mutli-path-collision-avoidance. My plan is to apply the function described above to the speed of both particles involved in a collision so that one is moving faster while the other moves more slowly, and vice versa, between the control points that the collision occurred within.